# Why I cant create HTML tags?

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Create HTML tags with JavaScript</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div1">
        <p id="p1">This is the first paragraph</p>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var paragraph = document.createElement("p");
        var nyje = document.createTextNode("That is a new paragraph");
        paragraf.appendChild("nyje");
        var div1 = document.getElementById("div1");
        div1.appendChild(paragraph);
    </script>
</body>    
</html>
```

I know it is basic stuff but my browser does not read my javascript codes. I am pretty sure that javascript is on. I use Google Chrome and my PC is Win Xp. Every time I open Google it tells me about end of support. Maybe this does not work because of that?

Comment: It's `paragraph`, not `paragraf`. Use `append` instead of `appendChild`.

Comment: [Open the browser's console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers). The error messages are shown there.

Comment: @Kinduser append is not a native javascript method, that's jQuery. .appendChild() is the vanilla javascript method to append elements to the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change your JavaScript to this:**

```
var paragraph = document.createElement("p");
var nyje = document.createTextNode("That is a new paragraph");
paragraph.appendChild(nyje);
var div1 = document.getElementById("div1");
div1.appendChild(paragraph);
```

**You had two errors:**

The variable name is `paragraph` not `paragraf`
You were entering a `string` called "nyje" instead of the variable name `nyje`